# unix command not working in python subprocess

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

The following command works fine on the shell

```
ssh hostname 'pgrep -fn "java -cp /strbase/apps/App"'
```

However not in the python subprocess, I have my array as follows

```
cmd_array = ['ssh', 'hostname', "'pgrep", '-fn', '"java', '-cp', '/strbase/apps/App"\'']
```

However I get no output.

I am trying below:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(
cmd_array, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

However

```
stdout
```

evalutes to an empty string, it should give me back a number. Why is this? It works fine in the shell?

Answer (score 1):

Your `cmd_array` is wrong, you send only two argument, hostname and your command string, it's should be :

```
cmd_array = ["ssh", "hostname", 'pgrep -fn "java -cp /strbase/apps/App"']
```